# Stubbing Warden on Controller Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stubbing, warden

I'm having an issue with testing my controllers and using Warden.

All examples point at stubbing `request.env['warden']`. This causes issues in my controllers when I call `env['warden']`, which then returns `nil`.

For a crude example, using this:

```
request.env['warden'] = double(Warden, :authenticate => nil,
                                          :authenticate! => nil,
                                          :authenticated? => false)
```

And a simple before filter like this:

```
before_filter do
  redirect_to new_user_session_url unless env['warden'].authenticated?
end
```

I get a `nil`.

I just managed to get it working using `controller.env['warden'] = ...` and it works.
This makes sense, since it's sitting right at the controller level, so I guess my question is what wouldn't it work in the I've seen all examples.

I have this in my `spec_helper`:

```
config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite many examples telling you to implement Warden through `env['warden']` in your Rails app. It seems the correct way to access it through `request.env['warden']`.

It found this out by raising env in my controllers during tests, and this always came out `nil`.

It seems in Warden, https://github.com/hassox/warden/blob/master/lib/warden/proxy.rb#L13
There is an accessor for the rack environment, which won't exist in test mode due to the absence of Rack in controller tests. *Please someone check this.*

So when stubbing `request.env` in RSpec, your implementation needs to point at `request.env`.

It seems a necessary evil in my mind. But if there is anyone with a good explanation or work around, I'd love to continue this discussion.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote controller test helpers for Warden.

http://kentaroimai.com/articles/1-controller-test-helpers-for-warden

Comment: I can verify that this works very well. Here's how to apply it to RSpec: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13422870/175981

Comment: Link is currently broken :(

Comment: @Intentss Could you please visit the following gist until I fix my website? https://gist.github.com/kentaroi/f210f45652ca1562c27ebdd945df5f14