# Stubbing out devise #authenticated and #unauthenticated in routing spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, stubbing

Devise adds the `#authenticated` and `#unauthenticated` constraints to the routing dsl but they rely on `request.env['warden']` responding to `#authenticate?`. As I understand it, the request doesn't exist in a routing spec so this fails with:

```
# NoMethodError:
#   undefined method `authenticate?' for nil:NilClass
```

Devise issues [#1670](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1670), [#1779](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1779) suggest that this is a limitation but don't suggest how to overcome it.

I decided to try to just stub out `authenticate?` but have never done stubbing before so this has been mostly hit-or-miss.

My first attempt looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'routes for Tenant' do
  it 'routes /organization to TenantsController#show' do
    allow_message_expectations_on_nil
    allow_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:authenticate?).and_return(true)

    expect(get: '/organization').to route_to(
      controller: 'tenants',
      action:     'show'
    )
  end
end
```

**The question:** I'm not comfortable stubbing `authenticate?` globally nor on `NilClass`. How can I stub this ... more generally ... so that I'm not cornered into a specific implementation?

I would like to somehow stub out `#authenticated` and `#unauthenticated` to simply ignore their implementation and `yield` but attempting to do that still results in the original `NoMethodError` as if my fake implementation doesn't exist:

```
expect_any_instance_of(ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper).to receive(:authenticated) { yield }
expect_any_instance_of(ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper).to receive(:unauthenticated) { false }
```

Why does it work the first way but not the second?

Comment: Why not just describe this in a controller spec? Part of the remit of controller specs is to test that redirects are happening as they should. I could be wrong but I think the remit of routing specs is more for ensuring that *publicly available* routes are available and correct, and that URLs which map to private routes are unroutable.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and the example I gave isn't a particularly good candidate for routing specs. I have actually moved that test into my controller spec. But the same issue still holds true for a handful of public routes that are defined inside of an `#unauthenticated` block. At this point, I'm just anxious to figure out why it doesn't work - and how to make it work - purely to scratch the itch. I was surprised when my first attempt worked and now I'm puzzled that the second attempt seems unworkable.

Comment: I spoke too soon. Now that I've put them in my controller spec they still fail with the same error.

Comment: Yes you're right... I believe the issue is that since Rack isn't loaded at all in RSpec tests, and so no Rack middleware is either, meaning Warden isn't loaded as it is a Rack middleware. You can shoehorn Warden into your tests (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13422870/2025180) but given the complexity perhaps it is best to just `include Warden::Test::Helpers` and use them to test your application, leaving the routing specs to only confirm that private URLs are not routable in the public namespace, and then in your controller tests confirm that users are redirected to the right place.

Comment: Even using the route spec in that manner is impossible due my routes file using the devise methods. My first example does solve the issue but is not acceptable to me. It seems like it should be possible to ignore the implementation details of authenticated/unauthenticated in my routes file and just stub them to provide the behavior I wish to test.

Comment: I have routing specs passing for routes behind devise without stubbing anything. The only item I have is `config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller` in my `spec_helper.rb`. If I was in a normal controller I would do a `before(:each)` and sign in my user. Can you run your initial attempt without the stub line?

Comment: I'm doing exactly that in my controller specs but even that does not allow `route_to` to work. I get the same error.