# Using Devise in rspec feature tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, devise

I've written the following rspec feature test spec:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "Team management", type: :feature do
  user_sign_in

  describe "User creates a new team" do
    ...    
    expect(page).to have_link("#{team_name}")
  end
end
```

The `user_sign_in` method is defined in my `rails_helper.rb`:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'

...

module UserSignInHelpers
  def user_sign_in
    before(:each) do
      @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]

      @current_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      @current_user.confirm

      sign_in :user, @current_user
    end
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.extend UserSignInHelpers,    type: :controller
  config.extend UserSignInHelpers,    type: :feature
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :feature
end
```

The `user_sign_in` method works from all of my controller specs but when I run my feature spec it fails with:

```
Team management
  User creates a new team
    example at ./spec/features/user_creates_a_new_team_spec.rb:19 (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Team management User creates a new team
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
     # /Users/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:24:in `setup_controller_for_warden'
```

I don't understand why this works in controller tests and not feature tests. Is there something I can do make this work in feature tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There is a basic problem with what you are trying to do. (`Devise` work on top of `Warden`)`Warden` is a
>   `Rack` middleware, but `RSpec` controller specs don't even include `Rack`,
>   as these types of specs are not meant to run your full application
>   stack, but only your controller code.

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17050993/2057388)

[`Test with Capybara`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara)

I have a simple support helper, that allows me to login and logout users:

```
module Auth
  def create_user!
    @user = User.create(email: 'foo@bar.com', password: '11111111')
  end

  def sign_in_user!
    setup_devise_mapping!
    sign_in @user
  end

  def sign_out_user!
    setup_devise_mapping!
    sign_out @user
  end

  def setup_devise_mapping!
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  end

  def login_with_warden!
    login_as(@user, scope: :user)
  end

  def logout_with_warden!
    logout(:user)
  end

  def login_and_logout_with_devise
    sign_in_user!
    yield
    sign_out_user!
  end

  def login_and_logout_with_warden
    Warden.test_mode!
    login_with_warden!
    yield
    logout_with_warden!
    Warden.test_reset!
  end
end
```

in a feature:

```
RSpec.describe "Team management", type: :feature do
  describe "User creates a new team" do
     login_and_logout_with_warden do
       # tests goes here
     end
  end
end
```

in a controller:

```
RSpec.describe "Team management", type: :controller do
  describe "User creates a new team" do
    login_and_logout_with_devise do
      # tests goes here
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you put Auth in spec/support/auth.rb? If so, how can I include it so that it is available to my controller and auth specs? I added `config.extend Auth, type: :controller` and `config.extend Auth, type: :feature` to `rails_helper.rb`. Here what happens when I try to run a test using Auth: https://goo.gl/Ce7a3d

Comment: i think you should use `include` instead of `extend` it's is different things `include` and `extend`.

Comment: If I want access to the @user variable in my specs I should use `include`?

Comment: Include is for adding methods(`login_and_logout_with_*`) to an instance of a class and extend is for adding class methods.